# Dots не работают на мобильных устройствах

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery, веб-программирование

Не могу понять почему не отображаются `dots` в панели навигации на мобильных устройствах.
Использую `Owl Carousel`.
Ссылка на [сайт][1].

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.carousel.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.theme.default.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    let block = $('#rec538998527');
    let wrap = $('.anku-slider');

    let slides = $('#rec539007376, #rec539059173, #rec539059177, #rec539059186, #rec539059192, #rec539059196, #rec539059494'); 

    let box = wrap.find('.tn-atom');
    box.append('<div class="owl-carousel owl-theme"></div>');
    slides.appendTo(block.find('.owl-carousel'));
    let owl = wrap.find('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
      loop: false,
      center: false,
      autoplay: true,
      autoplayTimeout: 5000,
      autoplayHoverPause: true,
      dots: true,
      nav: false,
      margin: 46,
      items: 7,
      responsive: {
        0: {
          items: 1
        },
        
        1200: {
          items: 2
        },
        
        1240: {
          items: 3
        },
      }
    })


    block.find("[href='#anku_left']").click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      owl.trigger('prev.owl.carousel');
    })
    block.find("[href='#anku_right']").click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      owl.trigger('next.owl.carousel');
    })
  });
</script>

<style>

  .anku-slider .t-rec .t396__artboard {
    width: 100% !important;
    height: 404px !important;
    word-break: normal !important;
    background: transparent !important;
  }

  @media screen and (max-width: 1199px) {
    .anku-slider .t-rec .t396__artboard {
      height: 404px !important;
    }
    

  }
  
  @media screen and (max-width: 959px) {
    .anku-slider .t-rec .t396__artboard {
      height: 404px !important;
    }
    
  }

  @media screen and (max-width: 639px) {
    .anku-slider .t-rec .t396__artboard {
      height: 404px !important;
    }
    
  }

  .anku-slider {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row nowrap;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: stretch;
    align-content: stretch;
  }

  .anku-slider .t-rec,
  .anku-slider .t396__artboard {
    overflow: hidden !important;
  }

  .anku-slider .t-rec .t396__artboard>.t396__carrier,
  .anku-slider .t-rec .t396__artboard>.t396__filter {
    display: none !important;
  }
  
  
</style>

``


  [1]: http://crimescenemoscow.ru/
```

Answer (score 0):

Увеличиваем высоту блока-родителя (актуально для Tilda).